# VB.net and mysql data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i'm working an attendance system and its almost done but i have a problem in my time in and time out form. i already did the codes for time in and time out of students and its working quite well but my problem is after the day ends it must reset the data so it can gather a new data when another day starts.

this is my code for time in and out

```
 Dim check As Boolean

    Call connect()
    Dim cmdd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) from attendance_for_student WHERE Remarks = 'IN' ", dbconn)
    Dim i As Integer = cmdd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmdd = Nothing
    dbconn.Close()
    TextBox1 .Text = i

    If student.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Scan Your Code!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    Else

        Call connect()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Sbarcode='" & student.Text & "'"
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader


        Do While dbread.Read
            Dim id As String = student.Text
            Dim folder As String = "c:\jpnhs\"
            Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, id & ".bmp")
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
            FULLNAME.Text = dbread.Item(1).ToString & " " & dbread.Item(2).ToString & " " & dbread.Item(3).ToString
        Loop
        dbread.Close()
        dbconn.Close()
    End If
    If Len(student.Text) = 8 Then
        Call connect()
        check = False

        sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance_for_student WHERE Sbarcode = '" & student.Text & "' AND (remarks <>'IN' OR remarks <>'OUT')"
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader

        Do While dbread.Read

            check = True
        Loop
        dbread.Close()
        dbconn.Close()




        If check = False Then
            Call connect()
            sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_for_student(Sbarcode,Time,Date,remarks) VALUES ('" & student.Text & "','" & LBLTime.Text & "','" & LBLDate.Text & "','IN')"
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            dbread.Close()

            dbconn.Close()
            Search_Code()

        Else
            Call connect()
            sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_for_student(Sbarcode,Time,Date,remarks) VALUES ('" & student.Text & "','" & LBLTime.Text & "','" & LBLDate.Text & "','OUT')"
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            dbread.Close()

            dbconn.Close()
            Search_Code()

        End If
    End If
```

Comment: My two pence in general: think about using "cmdd.Dispose()" instead of "cmdd = Nothing"! And try using parameters to avoid injections.

Comment: @muffi sir that line of code is for counting how many PRESENT student in the classroom. but i will take your advise. can you help me sir with the time in and time out problem? my codes up there already records the time in and time out of student but even another day comes when the student scans his/her barcode the remarks doesn't go back to time in and it shows time out even how many times the user scan his/her barcode it stays as time out in remarks.